# Django query over two tables without foreign key

Tags: django, django-models, django-orm

Hi i'm working on django. I have two models books and authors but there is no foreign key relationship between them.

Models:

```
class Books(models.Model):
  bookid = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
  bookname = models.CharField(max_length=50)
  authorid = models.CharField(max_length=50)

  class Meta:
    managed = False
    db_table = 'books'

class Authors(models.Model):
  authorid = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
  authorname = models.CharField(max_length=50)


  class Meta:
    managed = False
    db_table = 'authors'
```

Now, I'm want to fetch author and related books based on author name.

```
class Author_Books(generics.GenericAPIView):
def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    try:
        authorname = 'Author Name'

        # filtering authors

        authors = Authors.objects.filter(authorname__icontains=authorname)

        # get author related books 

            How to acheive it without using raw sql query.


        return HttpResponse(authors)

    except Exception as err:
        return HttpResponse(err)
```

Comment: You are doing it the wrong way. Make a foreign key relation between the two tables. Search for Books by author object as filtered by you earlier.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the below query.

```
for author in authors:
    books = Books.objects.filter(authorid = author.authorid )
```

**Note**: It is better to link the author and the books table.

Comment: This will not work - `authors` is a queryset, not an object.

Comment: That is why I suggested to use get instead of filter.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to use one SQL(join two tables) to fetch data from database, you must use django ForeignKey in models, otherwise django backend will query twice.
Like this

```
author = Authors.objects.get(pk=1)
books = Books.objects.filter(authorid=author.id)
```

if use foreignkey

```
books = Books.objects.filter(foreignkey__authorname=authorname)
```